# Python: Error passing user inputed variables between functions

Tags: python, function, variables

I am currently trying to build a simple ATM program(text based) from scratch. My problem is passing the user inputed variables between functions. The error I'm getting is ( **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given) ). Could someone explain what is happening and what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Atm:
    acctPass = 0
    acctID = 0

    def __init__(self, acctID, acctPass):
        #self.acctName = acctName
        #self.acctBal = acctBal
        self.acctPass = acctPin
        self.acctID = acctID

    def greetMenu(self, acctID, acctPass):

        while acctPass == 0 or acctID == 0:
            print "Please enter a password and your account number to proceed: "
            acctpass = raw_input("Password: ")
            acctID = raw_input("Account Number: ")
            foo.mainMenu()
            return acctPass, acctID # first step to transfer data between two functions

    def mainMenu(self, acctID, acctPass):
        print ""
        acctpass = foo.preMenu(acctPass, acctID)
        print acctPass
        print "Made it accross!"

    def deposit():
        pass

    def withdrawl():
        pass

foo = Atm()
foo.greetMenu()
```

Comment: `foo = Atm()` doesn't supply either `acctID` or `acctPass` - what were you expecting to happen?! And why don't the other methods use e.g. `self.acctID` instead of requiring the parameters again?

Comment: Note, rather than `foo.mainMenu()`, you should call `self.mainMenu()` (etc).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It still throws me an error that acctID and acctPass are not defined.

Comment: @mgilson are you referring to the last line of code or in def mainMenu()?

Comment: @JCD -- No, I'm refering to the calls in `mainMenu` and `greetMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = Atm()
```

passes exactly 1 argument to `Atm.__init__` -- the implicit `self`.  The other two arguments (`acctId` and `acctPass`) are missing so python complains.

It looks to me like you can get rid of `__init__` all together and bind the instance attributes in `greetMenu`:

```
class Atm:
    acctPass = 0
    acctID = 0

    def greetMenu(self):

        while self.acctPass == 0 or self.acctID == 0:
            print "Please enter a password and your account number to proceed: "
            self.acctpass = raw_input("Password: ")
            self.acctID = int(raw_input("Account Number: "))

        self.mainMenu()

# etc.
```

Here you'll still probably need to mess with `mainMenu` a bit to get it working (note now we're not passing the arguments around via function call arguments -- The values are stored on the *class*).

Comment: It still throws me an error that acctID and acctPass are not defined.

Comment: @JCD well **have you defined them anywhere**? You can't call `foo = Atm(acctID, acctPass)` unless you have *already assigned e.g. `acctID = 1`*.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the constructor called with `foo = ATM()`

```
def __init__(self, acctID=0, acctPass=0):
```

adding the `=0` to the parameters initializes them to 0 
and you have now overrode the constructor to accept 1,2 or 3 values.

in the greetmenu

```
def greetMenu(self, acctID, acctPass):

    while acctPass == 0 or acctID == 0:
        print "Please enter a password and your account number to proceed: "
        acctpass = raw_input("Password: ")
        acctID = raw_input("Account Number: ")
        foo.mainMenu()
        return acctPass, acctID # first step to transfer data between two functions
```

you need to either send in the parameters to the function `ATM.greetmenu(1234,'pwd')` or use the ones defined in the class like this.

```
def greetMenu(self):

    while self.acctPass == 0 or self.acctID == 0:
        print "Please enter a password and your account number to proceed: "
        self.acctpass = raw_input("Password: ")
        self.acctID = raw_input("Account Number: ")
        foo.mainMenu()

        #return acctPass, acctID # first step to transfer data between two functions
```